# Sublime text 2 - AutoComplete Brings irrelevant suggestions

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

Sometimes the AutoComplete feature, brings up some suggestions which are totally irrelevant to the context.

For example:

**MyModule.py :**

```
class test_1(object):
    def test_def(self):
        my_var_1 = 'sample text'

class test_2(object):
    def another_test_function(self):
        self.my_var_2 = 'another sample text'
```

**Conf.py :**

```
MY_CONF_1 = 12
MY_CONF_2 = 13
MY_CONF_3 = 14
```

**Test.py :**

```
import Conf
import TEST

print Conf.
```

The moment I type `Conf.` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) it brings up the options for `print` , `import` , `MyModule` , `Conf`.
 Which in the context it's irrelevant. It doesn't bring any of the variables inside the Conf.py file. 
(Well it does when I start typing `MY_C` )

I have tried "AllAutoComplete" and "CodeIntel" , but neither of them works as expected.

How can I force the AutoComplete to bring only available options relevant to the context?

P.S: The fuzzy search for AutoComplete sometimes works great, for example when you have you DB's table name some where and just typing it, but for majority of cases I can not rely on.

Comment: I think that Sublime's autocomplete only searches the current buffer, not other arbitrary files.  I don't think that it knows that the definition comes from Conf.py. (as an aside, you should use lower case module names.  See [the PEP8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)).

Comment: @dbw you're right, but that's what CodeIntel is for. I never heard of AllAutoComplete, I'm gonna give it a try, since I couldn't make CodeIntel run.

Comment: I hope there would be a Fix/Plugin for it. It would be very useful to have the context-sensitive auto-completes.

Comment: @enrey AllAutoComplete is a nice plugin, but it just lists everything, sometimes makes it even harder to find what you want.

Comment: @dbw, thanks for the the Styling tip